# Is there a way to find out if a server supports mod_rewrite & .htcaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to find out if a server supports mod_rewrite & .htcaccess

Comment: Are you running the server yourself, or going through a hosting provider? If you're running the box, it's as simple as looking in the config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a test scenario by adding mod_rewrite to .htaccess. There's an example [here](http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-test-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-t40.html).

Comment: To .htaccess thats the only way after all. Many hosts doesn't accept files named ".htaccess" or have AllowOverride disabled.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/apache_get_modules will output something similar to the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => core
    [1] => http_core
    [2] => mod_so
    [3] => sapi_apache2
    [4] => mod_mime
    [5] => mod_rewrite
)
```

Just look for mod_rewrite. You could even write a small function using in_array() to make it easier to determine whether a given module is loaded or not.

Comment: This does not show if rewrite rules can be set using a .htaccess

Comment: Good info and worth a vote, but I'm pretty sure that wouldn't tell you if 1. RewriteRules were on for your virtual domain or 2. AllowOverrides were on for your virtual domain.